# Redeclaring local variable

Tags: javascript

I was thinking that re-declaring a local javascript variable is ignored but I'm surprised that this function always returned "null". When I remove the "**var**" from the second "var  qty" declaration it started returning valid quantity.

What could be the reason? I'm using "use strict" in the top in Google chrome extension.

```
function get_quantity(firstname)
    {
        var qty = null;


                var firstindex = 3;
                var qtyindex = 5;


        $('#' + gg_first_id + " tr").each(function (index)
            {
                console.log("index=" + index);

                if (index == 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }



                var firstnamere = new RegExp(firstname,"i");

                if ($(this).find('td:eq(' + firstindex + ')').text().trim().match(firstnamere))
                    {
                       var  qty = $(this).find('td:eq(' + qtyindex + ')').text().trim();

                        qty = parseFloat(qty.replace(/,/, ''));


                        return false;

                    }

            });


        return qty;
    }
```

Comment: You made a new qty, in a new scope... of course changing it doesn't affect the other qty you're returning. (You're not "Redeclaring" anything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that redeclaring local variables is **not** ignored. What happens is that a **new** local variable `qty` is created, which *shadows* the old one in the context of `each` handler. As soon as `each` returns, the old variable is reinstated.

Comment: Thanks, I've searched  but I could not find this theory. Aren't all variable declarations hoisted in the top of function?

Comment: Ain't this related with function level scope?

Comment: @user5858: yes, but the function in this case the callback of each, not the outer one. Also hoisting is irrelevant here.

Comment: @LolCoder아카쉬: yep, that's what I was saying, wasn't I?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the point when reading for the first time +1

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue of scope.

When you define `qty` inside of the anonymous `function (index)` function, it creates a new local variable which exists only in the scope of that function. That local variable is its own variable, and has no connection to the wider-scoped `qty` variable.

Consider this:

```js
var i = 1;

//Expected value is 1
console.log(i);

function initVar(){
  var i = 2;
  
  //Expected value is 2
  console.log(i);
}

//Set the local variable inside the function to 2. Does not affect outer scope.
initVar();

//Expected value is 1
console.log(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add two simple examples based on @Unlocked's answer. As you can see in the example below you can see that the first `i` is bound to the outer scope and the other `i` is bound to the inner scope. As you can see when running the example `this === that` is true, meaning that `this.i` is the `i` of the outer scope, which is hidden inside the self invoking function due to the declaring of a variable with the same name.

```js
var i = 1
var that = this

;(function(){
  var i = 2
  
  // `i` of the inner scope
  console.log('i:', i)
  
  // `i` of the outer scope
  console.log('this.i:', this.i)
  
  // proving that `this` is the the outer scope
  console.log('this === that:', this === that)
})()
```

What you seem to think of is that all variables is instantiated (not declared) at the top of the scope, which is true but you have to know what is the scope. In the example below you can see that you can use `console.log()` before the variable is declared in the function, due to how Javascript works.

```js
;(function(){
  // `i` will be declared but not defined
  console.log('i:', i)

  var i = 1
})()

;(function(){
  // `i` will not be declared in this scope
  console.log('i:', i)
  
  function anonymous(){
    var i = 1
  }
})()
```